# Testing differences between groups in time course experiment

Tags: anova, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, manova

I want to analyze my data of glucose tolerance test experiment.
I have two groups- test and control, and we measured the glucose levels at 5 time points (0,15,30,60,120 min).
I want to test for difference between groups (null hypothesis-> glucose levels are the same for test and control in all time points) and I wonder which of the following test is the most appropriate:

**Option 1:** test on each time point + multiple test correction
Either t-test or non-paremetric test like Mann-Whitney. This will allow simple test on each time-point separately. I see two main drawbacks (1) for some timepoints I don't expect to have difference (like t0 and t120), which adds some irrelevant hypotheses to the correction. (2) We measure the effect on each timepoint separately and missing the effect of the test group relative to control for all timepoints.

**Option 2:** MANOVA
Modeling 'group ~ t0 +t1 +t2 .. + t5'. (each time point values are the glucose levels for that time).
For me it sounds like a good option mainly since model all time points together. The drawback is that a posthoc multiple-test corrected test is needed here so we are back to the (1) drawback of option 1.

**option 3:** 2-way ANOVA
model 'Glucose ~ C(Time_min) + C(group) + C(group)*C(Time_min)' C() for categorical.
Its feels like overkill--I'm really not interested to test either the interaction or the effect of time on glucose level. But, the p-value of group will actually answer my hypothesis. Another drawback is the redundant posthoc tests here (like pairs of test and control in different times).

Any inputs?